# How do I set up HTTPS on App Engine for free? (for a non custom domain)

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, https

I have a regular app set up on app engine that ends in appspot.com. I want to set up HTTPS for one page, appspot.com/securepage. How do I do this?

EDIT:
I added the secure parameter. Now my app.yaml looks like this (but it still doesn't work):

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: myapp.application

- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: handle_incoming_email.app
  login: admin

- url: /securepage
  script: myapp.application
  secure: always

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

inbound_services:
- mail
```

I map to securepage like this:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                    ('/', Home),
                    ('/securepage', RenderSecurePage),
                    LogSenderHandler.mapping()],
                    debug=True)
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add `secure: always` to each of the handlers that you want to be accessed over a https connection.

```
handlers:
  - url: /page1
    script: page1.app
    secure: always
```

When a visitor goes to `http://your-app-id.appspot.comm/page1` they will be automatically re-directed to the secure version `https://your-app-id.appspot.comm/page1`

You can also do the opposite, if required, to ensure a url is accessed only over an unsecure http:// url using `secure: never`

```
handlers:
  - url: /page2
    script: page2.app
    secure: never
```

See [this document](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Secure_URLs) for more detail.

Comment: What is page2 is rendered from the same python script? (Does it matter?)

Comment: No it doesn't matter.

Comment: Your /.* url handler needs to be moved down so that it is the last handler. Currently is it matching and so handling all requests.

Comment: It should not need to be changed as it is specified as a relative path in your script tag and so will use the same protocol (http or https) as the main page.